# How to set the credentials to send an email with AmazonSES using the PHP SDK from aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to use the latest SDK for PHP (v. 1.5.0). I am trying to send an email with AmazonSES. I have successully sent emails with the python scripts, so I know that my crendentials and other settings are okay.

I have copied the sample code however, it does not work. When calling AmazonSES, I get an error saying:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to AmazonSES::__construct() must 
be an array, string given, called in sendemail.php on line 31 and 
defined in sdk-1.5.0/services/ses.class.php on line 67
```

This is the code:

```
        $AWS_KEY = "AKIEDIEDEIMIAXEOA";
        $AWS_SECRET_KEY = "Te+EDEwjndjndededededededj";

        require_once("../library/lib_aws/sdk-1.5.0/sdk.class.php");

        $amazonSes = new AmazonSES($AWS_KEY, $AWS_SECRET_KEY);

        $response = $amazonSes->send_email( 
                    "from@email.com",
                    array("ToAddresses" => "to@email.com"),
                    array(
                        "Subject.Data" => "test",
                        "Body.Text.Data" => "body test",
                        )
                    );

        if (!$response->isOK())
        {
            echo "error";
        }
```

I cannot find how to set up the credentials correctly to send an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the config file format and the service constructors changed slightly in version 1.5. They mentioned this as a backwards-incompatible change in the release notes.

http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/PHP/3719565440874916

Answer (score 8):

The constructor for AmazonSES takes an array with options. Check the source:

https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/blob/master/services/ses.class.php#L55

You'll want to write it like:

```
$amazonSes = new AmazonSES(array(
    "key" => $AWS_KEY,
    "secret" => $AWS_SECRET_KEY
));
```

Please click through to the source (or [consult the docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html?r=4215)) to make sure there aren't other options you need to set.

Answer (score -2):

ToAddress's value must be an array, not a string.  This should work:

```
require_once('amazonsdk/sdk.class.php');

$ses = new AmazonSES(); 

$response = $ses->send_email(
    "senderaddress@example.com",
    array("ToAddresses"=>array('receiveraddress@example.com')), 
    array("Subject.Data"=>"Testing SES subject","Body.Text.Data"=>"Testing SES body.")
);

print_r($response);
```